# Loading file to neo4j using JS

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I'm doing a project on Neo4j.
The project is an HTML page were I receive information and I'm exporting the data to a file in a local directory using JS and then I need to load the file into Neo4j.

How can I load the file to Neo4j using JS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a CSV of the data you are receiving. Then you can insert it using cypher.
**Example**:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/specify_your_path/customers.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Node_lable{properties});
```

to access the correct location of CSV you've to put your CSV in

OR

You can go through [neo4j-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver) npm library. Using this you can embed the database connection in your code and directly insert your data into neo4j.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: was it useful?.

Comment: I’m not doing that way anymore, I’m trying to connect directly to Neo4j using JavaScript.